# UI Collection View, Alphabetical Scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tableview

I am trying to implement a Alphabetical Scroll list with a UICollectionView, I'm not sure if this is possible as I have only seen it with Table Views. At the moment the code I have seen to use with a table view is,

Here's a simple solution in Swift, assuming you have your title headers in an array. If the title couldn't be found, it will return the previous index in the array.

```
func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
return "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".characters.flatMap{String($0)}
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
return self.headerTitles.filter{$0 <= title}.count - 1
}
```

How can I change this to work with a Collection View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm aware Collection View also has sections and items. You just make it scroll vertically. And cell width equals to screen width. It'll look like table view.

Comment: Thank you very much for that, really helped me!